# MIPS Assembly Change integer and than print it out in that position

Tags: assembly, mips

I would like to be able to use a function to pass along an array, size and a value. Inside the function I want the 1st position of the array equal to the value that we pass along.

The equivalent in pseudo-code would be

```
function (array[10], size, value);
    array[0] = value;
    print(array[0]);
```

what I have in mips:

```
.data
array: .space 12 # my array of integers
size:  .word  3  # size of array
start: .word  5  # starter value

.text

main:

    la  $a1 array # loads $a1 with array buffer
    la  $a2 size  # loads $a2 with size of the user input
    la  $a3 start # loads $a3 with starter value
    jal fillArray

    li $v0 10
    syscall

fillArray:

    # this is where we make "array" at position 0 equal to "start"
    # this is where we print out "array" at position 0

    li $v0 1
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

I am really having a hard time understanding functions and arrays so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here is the answer:

```
sw $a3 0($a1) # saves $a3(start) to position 0 of array
```

You can do `addi $a1 $ai 4` to increment array